# Difference between "where you're from" and "where you've come to"

Tags: american-english, portuguese

I'm a Portuguese speaker and I am translating a video from English to my language. I now face this sentence

> "Are you a representative of where you're from or where you've come to?"

What is confusing is "where you've come to" because it somehow sounds contradicting. The "where you've come" would make one think of "where you've come **from**", but the "to" breaks this logic to my mind, since "to" would be, for instance, from here **to** there.

Comment: Could you provide us with more details? Are there any words that seem confusing? Does the meaning seem unclear? We'll need to know more.

Comment: I've edited the question adding what is confusing me. I hope it is understandable because it might be as confusing as it sounds to me.

Comment: Please see [ell.se]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**come to**, as defined by [TheFreeDictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/come+to):

> **4.** To arrive at or visit a particular place.
>
> *I came to this city because it's home to such beautiful architecture.*
>
> *I'll come to your house tonight and drop off your cake pan.*

This means that the person speaking the sentence is asking the listener if they are a representative of where the he/she originally came from (hence **where you're from**) or if the person is representing a place where he/she had previously arrived at, hence **where you've come to**.

For example, let's assume that you are a representative of Bulgaria who's originally from Bulgaria. That means you are representing the place **you're from**.

On the other hand, if you came from Ukraine but are currently representing the U.S., then you're representing the place **you've come to**.

Comment: Feedback much appreciated, since I don't really see **come to** being used in this sense that often.

Comment: I agree with your interpretation but think that the phrase has been deliberately used to make and emphasise the distinction, which is why it sounds odd. It also sounds challenging and a little agressive to me but, as you said in your original comment the question is very short of context.

Comment: Your points are definitely true. However, I still have a slimmer of hope that someone whips out a super esoteric and technical meaning of the word that actually doesn't sound super awkward in this context. As it stands, however, I don't really think additional context would help much in clarifying this sentence any further than I've attempted in my answer.

Comment: Also consider the possibility that it's figurative--e.g., you come from a poor farm community and you've _come to be_  a successful big-city banker.  Do you represent the farm or the city?

Comment: I see. Well, I guess this is clear enough for me. It is indeed something unusual. Thank you, @vth.